# Ran docker export

Tags: docker

I exported my image using `docker save <repository>:<tag> > image.rar` and then imported it onto another system using `docker import image.rar`.

I can see the image when I run `docker image ls`, but when I try to run it, it seems like no commands are found on the image.

For example:

```
# docker run -ti -p 3000:3000 myimage:latest /bin/bash
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

I noticed that some other articles mentioned to use `docker inspect` to check the "Cmd" value, but for whatever reason mine shows `null`

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:4e72a54a101b8acd79e2677180a616c8eda12c11833d346482a414e3e68247e3",
        "RepoTags": [
            "goku:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "Imported from -",
        "Created": "2019-08-08T05:42:16.776276679Z",
        "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "19.03.1",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 2072840786,
        "VirtualSize": 2072840786,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b44f261a6233b09181c456c250ea7b947602f79cdf4dd70670c13c40533167fc/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b44f261a6233b09181c456c250ea7b947602f79cdf4dd70670c13c40533167fc/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b44f261a6233b09181c456c250ea7b947602f79cdf4dd70670c13c40533167fc/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:a5ad36e48c9cf4342adb59c532661fb1320a2f5b6be8c30469d483415529c750"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2019-08-08T05:42:16.784693374Z"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm not quite sure what could have possibly gone wrong during the import. I thought I may have done this before successfully, but maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `docker load` instead of `docker import` and you should be good.

docker save => docker load

docker export => docker import

Above is the correct order

Look at the issue below
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7352